# Update price progrmmatically

Tags: magento2, product, upgrade, programmatically

I'm trying to update the price for configurable product programmatically. But the price is not updating.

Also I'm getting integrity constrain error when the sku is not assigned.

```
if($proType == 'configurable')
                {
                    $conf_product = $this->productRepository->get($sku);
                    //echo  $conf_product->getId(); exit;
                    $conf_product = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');
                    //$conf_product->setSku($sku);
                    $conf_product->setPrice($mapPrice); 
                    $conf_product->setStockData($is_in_stock);
                    try {
                        $conf_product->save();
                        $childIds = $this->updateConfigProduct($sku, $stock);
                        $logger->info('Stock updated for Config - Simple product:'.$sku);
                    } catch (Exception $ex) {
                        $logger->info('Stock update failed for:'.$sku.'-'. $ex->getMessage());
                        //continue;
                    }
                    
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        $specialPrice = $conf_product->getSpecialPrice();
            if($specialPrice > 0)
            {
                $configurableProduct = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($proId);
                $childrens = $configurableProduct->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProducts($configurableProduct);
                 foreach ($childrens as $children){
                     $childId = $children->getId();
                     $childproduct = $obj->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($childId);
                     $childproduct->setStoreId(0);
                     $childproduct->setSpecialPrice($specialPrice); 
                     $childproduct->save(); 
                }
           }
```

Comment: 2 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Zend_Db_Statement_Exception): SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'sku' cannot be null, query was: INSERT INTO `catalog_product_entity` (`entity_id`, `type_id`, `sku`, `has_options`, `required_options`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Exception #1 (PDOException): SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'sku' cannot be null

Comment: I've no idea about this error but if you are getting product ids you can update it with query in catalog_product_index_price directly according to your needs and logic.

Comment: I have managed to update the product. 
Thanks

Comment: If this question has helped you up vote it or if you've another solution kindly post it. So others can get help from it.